# How can i change a value of html tag after evry n sec with using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want a make a custom script.By using this script i want to change the value of a div after every 4 sec.
Is there any method by which i can do this?

Comment: you don't need to use any jquery code for that, use the `setInterval` function of the window object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) method which allows you to execute some function at regular intervals:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // This will execute on every 4 seconds
    var date = new Date();
    $('#someDiv').html(date.toString());
}, 4000);
```

and here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jh7rg/4/).